# incorrect value after casting double to a float

Tags: c, gcc, gdb, floating-point

I have some C code performing high precision arithmetic compiled by gcc(gcc (GCC) 4.4.4 20100726 (Red Hat 4.4.4-13)).The final result of the calculation is a double which has a value of 622.07999995861189.I am casting the double to a float.

frequency_value = (float)current_freq;

where current_freq is a double and frequency_value is a float.The value of frequency_value after the cast is 622.080017.I would expect the value to be 622.079956 as calculated in gdb by

(gdb) p (float)current_freq
$1 = 622.079956

Can anyone explain the large difference in values between that calculated by gcc and gdb.

Comment: What compiler flags/pragmas do you use with GCC?

Comment: I have compiled the code in debug mode with "-g  -O0".I get the same result with -O2 as well.I am not using any other specific gcc flags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A float has much less precision than a double; you lose about half the digits. So at best you'd be seeing the 622.0799 portion (rounded up to 622.0800). The difference you see is probably caused by the rounding mode in use.

Here are the actual numbers:

- As double: 622.0799999586118929073563776910305023193359375
- As float: 622.08001708984375 (internal representation: 1142654239)
- Immediately-preceding float: 622.0799560546875 (internal representation: 1142654238)

The internal representations are values generated using Java's `Float.floatToIntBits`. You can also use `Float.intBitsToFloat` to get back a floating-point number.

Comment: The difference is rather small:  0.000017131, though it does look like a big change written with characters.

Comment: @wallyk: It's small for a float, yes. For a double, you'd expect one [ulp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) to be much smaller than that, of course.

Comment: so the difference is rounding-up vs rounding-down ?

Comment: Hint: To change the rounding behaviour in C99, use [fesetround](http://man.he.net/man3/fesetround) from fenv.h

Comment: Hint2: If you have some time, read ["What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). It explains the whole details about that topic in a good manner.

Answer (score 1):

Floating-point values are usually stored in the machine in some binary format, not in some decimal format. For this reason, when you are truncating/rounding the number, it is unreasonable to expect that it will be truncated/rounded in therms of its decimal digits. I.e. it is unreasonable to expect that `622.07999995861189` will turn into something that necessarily begins with `622.07999...`. Some leading decimal digits should "survive" unchanged, but since the truncating/rounding is performed on binary representation (and what you see on the screen is the result of conversion the original binary format onto ASCII string) it is quite possible that the number of decimal digits affected by the process will be much greater than one might expect. In your case the change propagated all the way to the second digit after the dot. Which is why you got `622.08...` instead of `622.07...`.

As for the different result from GDB... It is quite possible that GDB's floating-point computation model is different from that of the compiler. For example, GDB might be truncating the result, while the compiler is rounding it. Or the compiler might be optimizing the computations, which often leads to a slightly different result.