# How is the result of this single-precision operation rounded? [Or why is this bit 1 and not 0?]

Tags: c, floating-point

I'm working on a function optimization routine (a variant of the Nelder-Mead algorithm) which fails to converge in very specific conditions.

I've identified that a `float` variable, let's call it `a`, is being assigned the mean between `a` and another variable `b` that differs from it by a bit only.

More precisely, the values of each variables are as follows:

```
float a = 25.9735966f; // 41CFC9ED
float b = 25.9735947f; // 41CFC9EC
```

And now I'm trying to assign to `a` the mean between `a` and `b`:

```
a = 0.5 * (a+b);
```

When I write this code in a test program, I get the result I want, namely `25.9735947`. But in the debugger of my original library code I see that the value of a remains `25.9735966`. I'm pretty certain that I have the same compiler flags on both programs. **Is there any reason why this single-precision calculation would yield different results?**

**UPDATE**

As @PascalCuoq requested, here is what I think is the assembly for the line in question. The line is doing a few other things though and I'm not sure where the multiplication happens.

```
.loc 1 53 0 discriminator 2
movl    -60(%rbp), %eax
cltq
salq    $3, %rax
addq    -88(%rbp), %rax
movq    (%rax), %rax
movl    -44(%rbp), %edx
movslq  %edx, %rdx
salq    $2, %rdx
leaq    (%rax,%rdx), %rcx
movl    -44(%rbp), %eax
cltq
salq    $2, %rax
addq    -72(%rbp), %rax
movl    -60(%rbp), %edx
movslq  %edx, %rdx
salq    $3, %rdx
addq    -88(%rbp), %rdx
movq    (%rdx), %rdx
movl    -44(%rbp), %esi
movslq  %esi, %rsi
salq    $2, %rsi
addq    %rsi, %rdx
movss   (%rdx), %xmm1
movl    -52(%rbp), %edx
movslq  %edx, %rdx
salq    $3, %rdx
addq    -88(%rbp), %rdx
movq    (%rdx), %rdx
movl    -44(%rbp), %esi
movslq  %esi, %rsi
salq    $2, %rsi
addq    %rsi, %rdx
movss   (%rdx), %xmm0
addss   %xmm1, %xmm0
movss   .LC6(%rip), %xmm1
mulss   %xmm1, %xmm0
movss   %xmm0, (%rax)
movl    (%rax), %eax
movl    %eax, (%rcx)
```

**CLARIFICATION**

My code is a <strike>ripoff</strike> variant of the Nelder-Mead code from Numerical Recipes. The offending line is this one:

```
p[i][j]=psum[j]=0.5*(p[i][j]+p[ilo][j]);
```

In this line, `p[i][j] == 25.9735966f` and `p[ilo][j] == 25.9735947f`. The resulting value in `p[i][j]` is `25.9735966f`.

Comment: I do not have an explanation yet, but 25.9735947 is the correct rounded to nearest **even** result, as I think you don't need me to tell you.

Comment: Any chance to see the assembly for `a = 0.5 * (a+b);` from the original library code? No other library linked in that might "helpfully" set the rounding mode?

Comment: When you say "in the debugger," do you mean when you inspect the values using the debugger, or do you mean that using the debugger version of this library, when run otherwise normally, produces different results?

Comment: @Pascal that's what I understood too. And I'm only 99.9% sure that those values are the ones being processed in the library code. But it would be very difficult for me to ascertain that.

Comment: @Scott No I mean running the library code (or more precisely, the program using the library) from a debugger.

Comment: @PascalCuoq if the line in question is line 53, would that be the section in the assembly code directly below a line that reads `.loc 1 53 0 discriminator 2` ?

Comment: @lindelof You said you were executing in a debugger, right? Assuming this debugger is GDB or uses the same commands as GDB, set a breakpoint just before the line and type "disassemble" at the prompt.

Comment: You do know that there is no number between a and b?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, that's right. I looked at the hex representation of a and b. There's only one bit of difference.

Comment: @PascalCuoq I've pasted the output from `disassemble` here: http://ideone.com/jq59h. It's the assembly for the whole function containing that line, isn't it?

Comment: The code for the assignment you are concerned with is around the `mulss` instruction. There is only one in the function, so there's no ambiguity. xmm0 and xmm1 are loaded with `a` and `b`, then added into xmm0 with `addss`. .LC6 should be a label where the constant 0.5 is stored, but it may be represented as an integer (1056964608). This completely excludes the possibility of some sort of double rounding: the instructions used are single-precision instructions from the SSE instruction set.

Comment: Hey wait... since 0.5 is a double literal, shouldn't the whole operation be done in double precision before being saved back in single?

Comment: @lindelof: No, only the multiplication, and the precision of the multiplication is irrelevant since `0.5` is a power of two.

Comment: This is reminiscent of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356741

Answer (score 2):

I just re-read the relevant part of IEEE 754-1985, assuming that your floating-point implementation conforms to that standard. The only thing that comes to mind is that there are different rounding modes in your two environments. These are the possibilities:

- round to nearest, and in case of equal distance: set the least significant bit to zero => `25.9735947f`
- round towards `+INF` => `25.9735966f`
- round towards `0` => `25.9735947f`
- round towards `-INF` => `25.9735947f`

So the only possibility is that your debugging environment has rounding mode *towards +INF*. To me, there is no other plausible explanation.

Comment: What about broken things like `-ffast-math`? Or what if the intermediate result is being computed at higher/lower precision?