# Double to Float Type Conversion -- Why can't I convert (double)20150813.00 to (float)20150813.00?

Tags: c++, floating-point

Why does `20150813.00` convert to `20150812.000000` and `20150708.000000` convert properly to `20150708.000000`?

Code Sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
        double one_o = 20150813.00;
        double two_o = 20150708.00;
        float one = (double)one_o;
        float two = (double)two_o;
        std::cout << std::fixed << "one_o = " << one_o << " one = " << one << std::endl;
        std::cout << "two_o = " << two_o << " two = " << two << std::endl;
        return 1;
}
```

Output is --

```
one_o = 20150813.000000 one = 20150812.000000
two_o = 20150708.000000 two = 20150708.000000
```

Help me understand double to float type conversion!

Edit:
`std::numeric_limits<float>().max()` reports `340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000` as the maximum to store in a `float`, which is far beyond what I'm attempting to store:

Comment: maybe the number exceeds the maximum size of a float number

Comment: float max = 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000 Found with the following: 
     std::cout << "float max = " << std::numeric_limits<float>().max();
Still don't understand how this answered in the other post..

Comment: Pick up your favorite language specification, and look for information about accuracy

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7356741/33499)

Comment: It's just a value that I'm trying to store inside a float as a float for further processing.

Comment: @Amit Which will then just refer to the [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) specification, so we can avoid the intermediate step.

Comment: The last digit is at the extreme end of what can and what cannot be stored in a float.

Comment: Wimmel -- Thanks, but it really doesn't address the question. To my understanding the rounding/truncation only occurs when you have a remainder, in this case I'm just trying to store a whole number in a float (with no decimal places)

Comment: std::numeric_limits<float>().max() reports 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000 as the maximum.. which is far beyond the number I'm trying to store?

Comment: You can store `340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000` *but not* `340282346638528859811704183484516925439.99999`, even though it is smaller.

Comment: @DumbCrabby Normal numbers are represented as (1.f)*2^(e-127) in IEEE-754 floating point math and you only have limited range for both f and e. Doubles have larger possible values for f and e, so you can get numbers you can't have with floats.

Comment: see algorithm of conversion from double to float in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737615/how-is-actually-done-floating-point-conversion-double-to-float-or-float-to-doub)

Comment: As an aside, storing dates in a floating-point format seems ridiculous...

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`float` can store much bigger numbers than `20150813`, but it cannot store big integers **precisely**.

Assuming [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) is used, the single precision `float` can store integers precisely at most 2<sup>24</sup>, which is `16777216`. Integers bigger than it will probably lose some precision.

Comment: And you were lucky with the second number as it is divisible by 4.